# Next question which depends on the button you press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a complete newb writing out a small little script in which the third question depends on what button you press on the second question, however I am completely lost as to how I should proceed :/

http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/uSuqB/6/

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Use radio buttons - that's exactly what they exist for. Give them all the same name, and upon clicking one of the radio buttons, show proper third question according to its value.

Comment: Hello Shadow Wizard, I thought about using radio buttons but decided on buttons for UI design practicability for users not used to computers. Thanks for your tip though!

Comment: @pufAmuf: Radio buttons are not really computer specific. Have you never seen "normal" survey that asked you to only choose one of the following options and you made your mark there? I think you can assume that everyone knows what they are doing (btw the term *radio button* comes from the old radios where pressing a button raised the previous selected button again, so it is really nothing new).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could bind a "special" click handler to the "special" element:

```
<input type="button" value="Something Special" id="specialthing">

$("#specialthing").click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'AgeVerification.jsp';
});
```

or:

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    switch(this.id) {
        case 'specialthing' : $("#specialDiv").show();
        case 'foo' : // so something else
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, is there a way to do one script for all 4 buttons that would activate a hidden div? - as in that button would set a value and execute to unhide a div so that I don't have to copy this script 4 times for each button?

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for :) Can I also do expansions with it (for exmaple: { statement1 stat2 stat3 } or do I have to do case: 'specialthing' do thing one ; case: 'specialthing' do thing two; ? :)